# Change css to "selected=selected value"

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

I am applying changes to the functionality and css of an e-commerce with shopify and I am stuck trying to change the css of the `selected = selected` option of my code.

The list:

[image]

And this the code:

HTML:

```
<select class="single-option-selector single-option-selector-{{ section.id }} product-form__input" id="SingleOptionSelector-{{ forloop.index0 }}" data-index="option{{ forloop.index }}">
   {% for value in option.values %}
      <option value="{{ value | escape }}"{% if option.selected_value == value %} selected="selected" class="selected-item"{% endif %} id="opcion-selector">{{ value }}</option>
   {% endfor %}
</select>
```

CSS:

```
#SingleOptionSelector-0 {
    margin-top: -5px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 3em;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    font-family: 'ITC Souvenir Std';
    background-color: #eef3eb;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: none;
}

#SingleOptionSelector-0 option {
    color: #eb3439;
    width: 2.5em;
    float: left;
    background-color: #eef3eb;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("SingleOptionSelector-0").size="3";
```

I tried to pass property inline:

```
<option value="{{ value | escape }}"{% if option.selected_value == value %} selected="selected" class="selected-item" style="color:red"{% endif %} id="opcion-selector">{{ value }}</option>
```

Also with the class that I create in each of the `selected` options via css through `selected-item`

I have even tried adding JavaScript style and `:checked` psuedo class.

I can't think of any other way to do it and I'm stuck with this.

Any idea?

Comment: Please may you post your css?

Comment: Was the :checked pseudo-class able to solve your problem? If not, let us know the CSS you are using, and can you clarify that the ".selected-item" class is in fact being properly applied to the element?

Comment: @Josh-WBS css just added

Comment: @JoeMajewski No it wasn't, that class was just a test to try to change the css. It shouldn't be there

Answer (score 2):

the :checked pseudo-class initially applies to such elements that have the HTML4 selected and checked attributes

```css
option:checked { display:none; }
```

```html
<select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It was the first thing i tried to use, it doesn't affect to the ```selected``` item